# VBA How to get notified with a message box once a web query complete

Tags: excel, vba

My worksheet has a web query connection. I use the following code to refresh the connection each time:

```
Sub Pull_data_from_JSE_Website()

'Pull data from JSE Website
    Sheets("Raw Data").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.Wait (now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
    MsgBox ("Web Query is Complete!")
End Sub`
```

I would like to be notified when the query is complete instead of using a timer. How can I do this?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean by "web query." Excel has querytables, query objects, background queries, workbookconnections, etc., and most of them have an AfterRefresh event or method (or similar) that you could use to pop your alert. What is the object type you're trying to refresh? See e.g., [QueryTable.AfterRefresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.afterrefresh) for events returning a boolean or [QueryTable.Refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.refresh) for a method that returns a boolean. You could trigger on either one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, in this case I have a background query which is scraping a table from a website. Seeing as the connection already exists in the workbook all I have to do is "Activeworkbook.RefreshAll". How can tie QueryTable.AfterRefresh into this scenario?

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case, does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73266685/10735864) work for you? Note that in the first example provided, there is a `.save` call after each connection is refreshed, and then an alert `MsgBox` call after all the connections have been looped through. The other examples in that answer would help you ID your specific connection and refresh only that connection if you wanted to, and then you could add the `.save` and `MsgBox` alert code after that as shown in the first example.